# What is the shortcut to close up / zoom to face / vertex / edge while modelling?

Tags: 3d-view

What is the shortcut to close up / zoom to face / vertex / edge while modelling?
I mean, the button or shortcut to see the part of the model that you are selecting on detail, maybe for big models?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

View selected is <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> (the full-stop/period/decimal point on the numpad)

It is also available from *3D view > View > Align View > View Selected*.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use "." period in edit mode it helps a lot in modelling also if you select multiple vertices same thing happens yet different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I will mention 3 shortcut which can zoom.

1. As mention above <kbd>Numpad.</kbd> to selected mesh (If you have many mesh and want to zoom selected mesh)

[image]

2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+ on Numpad</kbd> that will zoom and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>- on Numpad</kbd> unzoom

[image]

3. If you want to zoom some selected area. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. As soon as you press it you will get white horizontal and vertical dot line drag on the area where you need to zoom.

[image]